# Как заставить переменную Button в атрибуте command передавать себя? Tkinter

Tags: python, функции, классы, tkinter, button

Господа, прошу помощи.
Задача вроде простая, но не могу сообразить в упор.
Занимаюсь в tkinter, есть 3 кнопки при нажатии на которых должны меняться каждый раз цвета, загвоздка в том, что как в функцию передавать саму переменную?
Привожу код:

```
counter = 1

def choose():
   if counter % 2 != 0:
     текущая_кнопка.config(background='#11DDDD')
     counter += 1
   else:
      текущая_кнопка.config(background='#22DDDD')
      counter += 1

button_1 = Button(window, background='#DDDDDD', command=choose)
button_2 = Button(window, background='#DDDDDD', command=choose)
button_3 = Button(window, background='#DDDDDD', command=choose)

button_1.place(x=35, y=83, width=108, height=95)
button_2.place(x=35, y=183, width=108, height=95)
button_3.place(x=35, y=283, width=108, height=95)
```

Как мне сделать, как это делается в классах - через self. Не могу понять, так как при создании данного экземпляра я ему указываю функцию, но как в эту функцию передать текущий созданный экземпляр класса?

Comment: Отдельной строкой через config: `button_1.config(command=lambda: choose(button_1))` (только в choose добавить параметр)

Comment: Я всё понял. Огромное вам спасибо - всё получилось! =)